# In mongodb-go-driver, how to marshal/unmarshal BSON in to a struct

Tags: mongodb, go

I am new to mongodb-go-driver. But i am stuck.

```
cursor, e := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("name", id)))

for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {

    e := bson.NewDocument()
    cursor.Decode(e)

    b, _ := e.MarshalBSON()
    err := bson.Unmarshal(b, m[id])
}
```

When look at the contents of m[id], it has no content - all nulls.

My map is like this : 
    m   map[string]Language

and Language is defined like :

```
type Language struct {
    ID         string   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`                   // is this wrong?
    Name       string   `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Vowels     []string `json:"vowels" bson:"vowels"`
    Consonants []string `json:"consonants" bson:"consonants"`
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am learning using this example : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/examples/documentation_examples/examples.go

Comment: line `cursor.Decode(e)` returns error too. add its result in your question

Comment: No. If I print e I see valid BSON data from MongoDB

Comment: i mean the function `Decode()` returns error too. print the error here if its not nil

Comment: Yes, you are right. `Decode(interface{}) error` is the definition of `Decode`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The official MongoDB driver uses the objectid.ObjectID type for MongoDB ObjectIds. This type is:

`type ObjectID [12]byte`

So you need to change your struct to:

```
type Language struct {
    ID         objectid.ObjectID   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`             
    Name       string   `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Vowels     []string `json:"vowels" bson:"vowels"`
    Consonants []string `json:"consonants" bson:"consonants"`
}
```

I had success with:

```
m := make(map[string]Language)
cursor, e := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("name", id)))

for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {

    l := Language{}
    err := cursor.Decode(&l)
    if err != nil {
        //handle err
    }
    m[id] = l // you need to handle this in a for loop or something... I'm assuming there is only one result per id
}
```

Comment: may I ask, do you really need the _id checked out from Mongodb?

Comment: I notice that this struct describes both JSON and BSON serialisation. This feels like the same struct that is 'fetched' from the database is then presented to the user as JSON without transformation, essentially exposing your data structures directly to the client. As a relative newcomer to Go,  I am genuinely very curious as to whether this is really considered good practice? Is this idiomatic go?

Comment: I will leave the "is this idiomatic go?", to the experts to answer. You can always use `Field int json:"-"` to avoid sending a field to client

Answer (score 23):

Newer "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver" expects object IDs defined as

```
type Application struct {
    ID      *primitive.ObjectID `json:"ID" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
}
```

This serializes into JSON `"ID":"5c362f3fa2533bad3b6cf6f0"` and here is how you get the ID from insert result

```
if oid, ok := res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID); ok {
    app.ID = &oid
}
```

Convert from string

```
appID := "5c362f3fa2533bad3b6cf6f0"    
id, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(appID)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
_, err = collection.DeleteOne(nil, bson.M{"_id": id})
```

Convert into string

```
str_id := objId.Hex()
```

Answer (score 8):

**Update:**
New changes were made recently, now have to change to:

```
import "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/primitive"

type Language struct {
    ID         primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"` // omitempty to protect against zeroed _id insertion         
    Name       string   `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Vowels     []string `json:"vowels" bson:"vowels"`
    Consonants []string `json:"consonants" bson:"consonants"`
}
```

And take the ID value:

```
log.Println("lang id:", objLang.ID)
...
```

Comment: That works, but this will JSON serialize into `"ID":{"Type":7,"Value":"XDYvP6JTO607bPbw"}`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting

`cannot decode objectID into an array`

so i changed to

`` ID interface{} `bson:"_id,omitempty"` ``

without any issues